# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier when Compiling

Tags: mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

This is betting smart contract, the issue is the user/address need to bet on different matches. The smart contract design only on one mapping value. Full source code:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingMatch/blob/main/bettingMatch.sol

```
contract Betting is Ownable {
   
   uint256 public minimumBet;
   
   event EtherTransfer(address beneficiary, uint amount);
   //Initialize in 10 matches (It can be improved)
   uint256[] public totalBetHome = new uint256[](100);
   uint256[] public totalBetAway = new uint256[](100);
   uint256[] public totalBetDraw = new uint256[](100);
   uint256 public numberOfBets;
   uint256 public maxAmountOfBets = 1000;
    
   uint256 devFee = 9500;
   
   address[] public players;

   address public owner;
   
   struct Player {
      uint256 amountBet;
      uint16 matchSelected;
      uint16 resultSelected;
   }
   
   mapping(uint16 => uint16[]) matchInfo;
   
   mapping(address => bytes32[]) userAdd;
   
   mapping(uint16 => uint16[]) selectedResult;
   
   mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) betAmount;
   
   mapping(uint16 => bool) matchBettingActive;

   mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;

   function() public payable {}

   constructor() public {
       owner = msg.sender;
      //The minimum Bet defined as 0.0001 ether
      minimumBet = 100000000000000;


   }
   function kill() public {
      if(msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }

   function checkIfPlayerExists(address player) public view returns(bool){
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
         if(players[i] == player) return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   
   function checkIfMatchStatus(uint16 _match) public view returns(bool){
   if(matchBettingActive[_match] == true){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
       }
   }
   
   function _checkBetMatchIsValid(address _user, uint16 _matchId, uint16 _chosenWinner) private view returns (bool) {

        //ensure that user hasn't already bet on match 
       uint16[] storage addUser = userAdd[_user]; 
        if (addUser.length > 0) {
            for (uint n = 0; n < addUser.length; n++) {
                if (addUser[n] == _matchId) {
                    //user has already bet on match 
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        uint8 participantCount; 
        if (_chosenWinner >= participantCount)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

   function initializeMatches(uint8 _numberMatches) public onlyOwner{
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < _numberMatches; i++){
         totalBetHome[i] = 0;
         totalBetAway[i] = 0;
         totalBetDraw[i] = 0;
      }
   }
   
   function beginVotingPeriodForMatch(uint16 _match)  public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    matchBettingActive[_match] = true;
    return true;
  }
  
   function closeVotingForMatch(uint16 _match) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    // Close the betting period
    matchBettingActive[_match] = false;
    return true;
  }

   function bet(uint16  _matchSelected, uint16  _resultSelected) public payable {
       require(matchBettingActive[_matchSelected] == true, "Betting: match voting is disabled");
      //Check if the player already exist
    //   require(!checkIfPlayerExists(msg.sender));
    
      //Check if the value sended by the player is higher than the min value
      require(msg.value >= minimumBet);
      
      require(!_checkBetMatchIsValid(msg.sender,_matchSelected, _resultSelected));
      
      matchInfo[] storage idMatch = _matchSelected;
      idMatch.push(msg.sender, _matchSelected, _resultSelected);
      
      bytes32[] storage userBets = userAdd[msg.sender];
      userBets.push(_matchSelected);
       
      
      //Set the player informations : amount of the bet, match and result selected
     //   playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
    //   playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected = _matchSelected;
    //   playerInfo[msg.sender].resultSelected = _resultSelected;
      
      
      
      //Add the address of the player to the players array
      players.push(msg.sender);
    
      //Finally increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
      if ( _resultSelected == 1){
          totalBetHome[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
      }
      else if( _resultSelected == 2){
          totalBetAway[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
      }
      else{
          totalBetDraw[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
      }
   }

   function distributePrizes(uint16 matchFinished, uint16 teamWinner) public onlyOwner {
      address[1000] memory winners;
      //Temporary in memory array with fixed size. Let's choose 1000
      uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
      uint256 loserBet = 0; //This will take the value of all losers bet
      uint256 winnerBet = 0; //This will take the value of all winners bet
      address add;
      uint256 bets;
      address playerAddress;
    
      //Check who selected the winner team
      for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
         playerAddress = players[i];
         //If the player selected the winner team, we add his address to the winners array
         if(playerInfo[playerAddress].matchSelected == matchFinished &&
            playerInfo[playerAddress].resultSelected == teamWinner){
            winners[count] = playerAddress;
            count++;
         }
       }
       //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
       if ( teamWinner == 1){
         loserBet = totalBetAway[matchFinished] + totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
         winnerBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished];
       }
       else if ( teamWinner == 2){
         loserBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished] + totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
         winnerBet = totalBetAway[matchFinished];
       }
       else{
          loserBet = totalBetHome[matchFinished] + totalBetAway[matchFinished];
          winnerBet = totalBetDraw[matchFinished];
       }
      //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
      for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
          //Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
         if(winners[j] != address(0))
            add = winners[j];
            bets = playerInfo[add].amountBet;
            uint256 amountToPlayer = (bets * (10000+(loserBet*devFee/winnerBet))) / 10000;
            winners[j].transfer(amountToPlayer);
      }
      //Reset all variables
      delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; 
      players.length = 0; 
      loserBet = 0; 
      winnerBet = 0;
      //10 will be the number of matches (To improve this)
      for(uint256 k = 0; k < 10; k++){
         totalBetHome[k] = 0;
         totalBetAway[k] = 0;
         totalBetDraw[k] = 0;
      }
    }
```

Betting Smart Contract, trying to create a mapping structure that user/wallet_address can bet on multiple matches. The problem of this betting contract is every time the user/wallet_address place a bet, the data of single mapping overwrite, how to create a mapping of value so that user/wallet_address can bet on different matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2-dimensional mapping for this purpose, e.g. `mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => Player)) playerInfo`, which will be mapping: player address -> matchSelected -> Player struct and you could modify the Player struct to hold only attributes `amountBet` and `resultSelected` and to fit into 8 bytes to save on gas costs.